# How to call bootstrap modal in a loop using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a code here that will insert data on database, it will filter first if the data already exist and ask user if he/she want to continue inserting data using bootstrap modal. now the problem is it only show at the end of the loop, what i want is every time a data has been found on database a popup modal will show.

```
$.each(person, function(index, value){
    var existing = DisticntVal(value);

    if(existing == 0){
        InsertPerson(value);
    }else{
        var a = ConfirmYesNo(value['person'] + " already exist. Do you want to continue?");
        a.then(function (b) {
            if(b == 1){
                InsertPerson(value);
            }
        });
    }

});

function ConfirmYesNo(msg) {
    var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();
    var $confirm = $('#exampleModal');
    $confirm.modal('show');
    $('#message').html(msg);

    $('#btnyes').off('click').click(function () {
        $confirm.modal('hide');
        dfd.resolve(1);
        return 1;
    });
    $('#btnno').off('click').click(function () {
        $confirm.modal('hide');
        return 0;
    });
    return dfd.promise();
}

function DisticntVal(person) {
    var returncount;
    var nperson = JSON.stringify(person);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'chckdistinct.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {person: nperson},
        async: false,
        success: function(response) {
            returncount = response;
        },
        error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
        }
    });
    return returncount;
}
```

```html
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p id="message"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" id="btnno">No</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnyes">Yes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Need help with this one.

Comment: "it only show at the end of the loop". Ok but since we can't see your data, and we cannot see what the `DisticntVal` _[sic]_ function does, we can't really say whether that's actually the correct behaviour or not.

Comment: What i'm trying to do is like confimr() function of javascript which pauses loop until button event has been click then continue.

Comment: ConfirmYesNo doesn't pause execution, it just makes that bit of HTML (the modal) visible, and then continues. So before your user gets chance to respond to the modal, the loop continues again and again, but just overwriting the modal contents and event handlers with the latest contents. The older promises etc never get resolved. Another piece of advice: `async: false` is a bad idea. It causes bad user experience (the browser is locked up for the duration of the ajax request, and nothing can be clicked on) and is also already deprecated, so browser will probably remove the feature in future.

Comment: Give me a bit of time, I will see if I can think how to structure this better.

Comment: Wow thanks im having a hard time looking for a way to pause a loop. And btw what ekse can I use to return ajax value instead of async false.

Comment: I'm not surprised, because basically you can't, short of using a bog-standard browser "confirm" box (rather than a HTML modal). A simple solution is not to actually use a loop at all...see my answer

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that your `ConfirmYesNo` function doesn't pause execution of the loop. It just makes that bit of HTML (the modal) visible, and then continues. So before your user gets chance to respond to the modal, the loop continues again and again, but almost instantly overwrites the modal contents and event handlers with the next set of contents, until it gets to the end. This is why you appear to only see the last item. The other items do get displayed, but they are overwritten so quickly you're unlikely to actually be able to see them, and the older promises never get resolved.

Another piece of advice: `async: false` is a bad idea. It causes bad user experience (the browser is locked up for the duration of the ajax request, and nothing can be clicked on) and is also already deprecated, so browser will probably remove the feature in future.

Here is an alternative solution based entirely on promises, avoiding the use of a loop at all. I have modified it slightly to make it runnable in this snippet, but I have left the bits of your original code which I couldn't use commented out, so that you can see where to restore them. I also had to guess the structure of your person objects, so you may need to change that back to suit your real data.

```js
var people = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "A"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "B"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "C"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "D"
  }
];

$(function() {
  $("#begin").click(processInserts);
});

function processInserts() {
  processIndividualInsert(0);
}

function processIndividualInsert(index) {
  if (index < people.length) {
    var person = people[index];

    return distinctVal(person).then(function(existing) {
      if (existing == 0) {
        console.log(person.name + " doesn't exist");
        insertPerson(person);
        return processIndividualInsert(index + 1);
      } else {
        return ConfirmYesNo(person.name + " already exists. Do you want to continue?").then(function(b) {
          if (b == 1) {
            console.log(person.name + " already exists. User opted to continue with the insert anyway");
            insertPerson(person);
            return processIndividualInsert(index + 1);
          } else {
            console.log(person.name + " already exists. User opted not to continue with the insert");
            return processIndividualInsert(index + 1);
          }
        });
      }

    });
  } else {
    console.log("All completed");
    return false;
  }
}

function distinctVal(person) {

  //generate arbitrary dummy response data:
  var response = 0;
  if (person.id % 2 == 0) response = 1;
  //dummy promise for testing:
  var prom = $.Deferred();
  prom.resolve(response);
  return prom.promise();

  //this would be your real code instead of the dummy code:
  /*
  return $.ajax({
    url: 'chckdistinct.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
      person: JSON.stringify(person);
    },
    error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
      console.log(xhr);
      console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
    }
  });*/
}

function ConfirmYesNo(msg) {
  var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();
  //dummy code to avoid bootstrap
  $('#exampleModal').show();

  //your real code would be:
  /*var $confirm = $('#exampleModal');
  $confirm.modal('show');*/
  $('#message').html(msg);

  $('#btnyes').off('click').click(function() {
    //dummy code to avoid bootstrap
    $('#exampleModal').hide();
    //your real code would be:
    /*$confirm.modal('hide'); */
    dfd.resolve(1);
  });
  $('#btnno').off('click').click(function() {
    //dummy code to avoid bootstrap
    $('#exampleModal').hide();
    //your real code would be:
    /*$confirm.modal('hide'); */
    dfd.resolve(0);
  });
  return dfd.promise();
}

function insertPerson(person) {
  //don't know what's supposed to go in here, but presumably another async ajax call which will insert the person data
  return true;
}
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="begin">
  Click to Begin
</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p id="message"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" id="btnno">No</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnyes">Yes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```